# Regular Expression to split a sentence into hyphenated words

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regular expression that will split a sentence into words, by using both spaces and hyphens as the character to split at. i.e. "This is over-done" should return 4 words (this, is, over, done)

I have the RegEx to do these separately but can't get it to work together:

To split on spaces:

```
\b(\S)(\S*)\b
```

and to split on hyphens:

```
\b([^-])([^-]*)\b
```

I have tried various ways to put these together but can't get it working. Any help appreciated.

Comment: what language? JS? PHP?

Comment: `\W+` should work, e.g. in JS `str.split(/\W+/)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
\b([^-\s]+)\b
```

Comment: So simple when you know how!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
(?:^|[\s-])?(\w+)(?:$|[\s-])?
```

Demo: http://rubular.com/r/WiRSwFPTXa